# Reflexive sheaves on stable curves-II

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

This is an extension of [Reflexive sheaves on stable curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203642/reflexive-sheaves-on-stable-curves).
Let $C$ be a stable curve and $\mathcal{F}$ a reflexive sheaf on $C$ supported on the whole of $C$. Is the projective dimension of $\mathcal{F}$ less than or equal to $1$?

Comment: NO. Let $\pi :\tilde{C}\rightarrow C $ be the normalization of $C$, and $\mathcal{F}:= \pi _*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{C} }$. By the answers to your previous question (or by easy direct computations), $\mathcal{F}$ is reflexive, $\mathrm{pd}(\mathcal{F})=\infty$ and $\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F})=C$.

Comment: @abx: Could you please give a hint on why $\mathcal{F}$ is reflexive?

Comment: Let $R\cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ be the completion of the local ring of $C$ at a double point; then $\tilde{R}=R/(x)\oplus R/(y) $.